# Database table for price/quantity (tier prices)?

Tags: product, database, quantity, tierprice

Where is the table in tho database that manages the role product/quantity?

I need to synchronize this to another table in another database.

Comment: have you need shopping cart rules tables?

Answer (score 5):

The tier prices are stored in the `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` table. There is also an index table of the tier prices (`catalog_product_index_tier_price`) which contains aggregated data from the former table combined with catalog price rules if I remember correctly.

But you probably want to use the `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`

Comment: i inserted the new role in cart:
if sku is product-test and qty is 10000 --> price euro 20.

I watched the table catalog_product_entity_tier_price, catalog_product_index_tier_price, catalog_product_entity_tier_price but it's is empty

Comment: @AlessandroGnola, this is probably a Shopping Cart Price Rule you have set, right? These are in the `salesrule*` tables. This is not tierpricing...

Comment: @7ochem gotta love pricing in Magento ;) would be nice to have a diagram of pricing structure, ever came across something like that?

Comment: @AnnaVölkl's database diagram is a start ;) But seriously, yeah, there should be some flow charts of the more complex processes added to the docs.

Comment: @7ochem right?! maybe something we could do at a hackathon for M2

Comment: Solved! I have done a script using Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule'). This work with table salesrule.
I tryed insert the role direcly into table but there are 2 fields serialized. It's impossible.